# Building a Docker image from a private GitHub repository with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I know it's possible to supply a GitHub HTTP URL as a service's build context:

```
version: '3.9'

services:
  my-app:
    build: https://github.com/rambo/my-app.git
```

The above works well for public repos. But what if the `Dockerfile` is stored in a private repo that requires authentication (e.g. via SSH). Is something like the below example supported?

```
services:
  my-app:
    build: ssh://git@github.com:rambo/my-app.git
```

I've tried multiple variations of the above configuration but nothing seems to work.

Comment: I think the repository should contain the whole required sources. Or you should build an image based on the code, push to Docker Registry and then use in the Docker Compose

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can achieve this by using github **personal access token** which have read access only
https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token

And then your token is your username with empty password

Like,
https://{token}@github.com/org_name/repo.git

Comment: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via personal access token, as described by @vivek-bani, or using SSH:

```
  your_service_name:
    container_name: foo-service
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-compose
      context: git@github.com:orgname/yourrproject.git#feature-branch
      ssh: [ "default" ]
    stdin_open: true
    ports:
      - "7000-7051:7000-7051"
```

Here, `ssh: [ "default" ]` indicates to docker compose that it should "[mount the default ssh agent](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#ssh)."

Comment: This approach isn't successful for me, at least using BuildKit:
The command `DOCKER_BUILDKIT=1 docker build --ssh default -t "$TAG" -f "$DOCKERFILE_PATH" "$BUILD_CONTEXT"` where `DOCKERFILE_PATH=/path/to/local/Dockerfile` and BUILD_CONTEXT=git@bitbucket.org:my_company/repository.get#master` gives the error `failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount238172078/path/to/local/Dockerfile: no such file or directory`. I've been able to successfully use git ssh commands in the Dockerfile.