# Is there a way to use a Github PAT for building a Docker image from a private Github Repo?

Tags: git, docker, github, docker-build

I have a private repository that includes a folder "python" with a Dockerfile that I would like to build on a Linux machine. Ideally, I would like to use my Personal Access Token to authenticate myself.

For public repositories, the correct code seems to be:

docker build -t example_tag github.com/user/repo

However, this then asks for a username and password which is unfeasible for automating.

I tried the solution provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65312857/building-a-docker-image-from-a-private-github-repository-with-docker-compose) but this does not seem to work. It returns:

> unable to download remote context
> https://{TOKEN}@github.com/{ORG}/{repo}#master:python

Does anyone have any other possible solutions or is there a better way of creating Docker images from private repos (other than Github Action which I am not using due to limitation in frequency that they can be used)?

Thanks so much in Advance!

Comment: Can you `git clone` the repository normally, and then `docker build .` the local tree, without using a GitHub URL?

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @David-Maze. I implemented a bash script around this idea in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this.  Pass your personal access token in as a build argument, say, `GIT_TOKEN`.  You can then use [this answer from the Git FAQ](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitfaq#http-credentials-environment) inside the container to set up a credential helper (swap out the username):

```
$ git config --global credential.helper \
    '!f() { echo username=author; echo "password=$GIT_TOKEN"; };f'
```

That will configure your containerized Git to read the password from the `GIT_TOKEN` environment variable that you've passed into the container.

Note that because build arguments are preserved in containers, in order for you to securely use this approach, you *must* use a multi-stage build.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did end up choosing the solution suggested by David Maze but this was helpful nonetheless.