# docker compose doesn't find Dockerfile in git repo

Tags: git, docker, docker-compose

I try to build a docker container with docker compose from a private git repo which includes the Dockerfile.
Docker 24.0.7 on a Raspberry Pi 4 with debian bullseye.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  creideiki:
    build: 
      context: ssh://hab@haoke:22/data/Git/py_wunsch.git#main
      ssh:
        - default
    environment:
      - SSH_AUTH_SOCK=${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
    volumes:
      - ${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}:${SSH_AUTH_SOCK}
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3031:3031"
```

I try

```
hab@tsht:/data/creideiki_test $ docker --log-level debug compose --progress=plain build
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/home/hab/.docker/buildx" 
#0 building with "default" instance using docker driver

#1 [creideiki internal] load git source ssh://hab@haoke:22/data/Git/py_wunsch.git#main
#1 0.252 Warning: Permanently added the ECDSA host key for IP address '192.168.2.8' to the list of known hosts.
#1 0.513 aa8cb0051360c52b27cf3781d6f6a07409c0d6ba       refs/heads/main
#1 DONE 0.7s

#1 [creideiki internal] load git source ssh://hab@haoke:22/data/Git/py_wunsch.git#main
#1 CACHED
DEBU[0000] using default config store "/home/hab/.docker/buildx" 
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0000] stopping session                              span="load buildkit capabilities"
DEBU[0000] serving grpc connection                      
DEBU[0002] stopping session                             
failed to solve: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount2916653639/ssh:/hab@haoke:22/data/Git/py_wunsch.git#main/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

There **is** a Dockerfile in the root directory of the git repo. So the build process should start.

Why doesn't find docker the Dockerfile?

BTW: `git clone -b main ssh://hab@haoke:22/data/Git/py_wunsch.git` works and can build the image.

Comment: Passing SSH stuff as an env variable to the container does not help with the build phase. Try adding ssh: [ "default" ] under build, like here https://stackoverflow.com/a/75806275/6845813. I'm not sure if it will solve the problem though, someone has commented on having problems with this approach.

Comment: ssh: -default is the same. And you are right, the SSH_AUTH_SOCK lines are remains from trying to get the ssh git access working. That's not the problem though - it seems to load the git repo.